# How to properly organize folders of links to binary files in multi-project Project Groups in Delphi RAD Studio?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, dfm, project-settings, dcc32

How to properly organize folders of links to binary files in multi-project Project Groups in Delphi RAD Studio so that you can compile the entire project group without manually copying files?

I have several packages and an executive project in the Project Group.

The main executive project references functions and classes from packages.

The packages contain the setting 'Unit output directory:' where to upload compiled files.

In the settings of the main executive project, the setting "Delphi Compiler - Search path" is set to the folders specified in the "Unit output directory" for Packages.

Thus, the Main project has access to the packages dcu files.

But when compiling the Main project, the compiler gives a compilation error that it cannot find *.dfm package files.

I checked the standard RAD Studio 22.0\lib\win32\release folders. These folders contain dfm files.

This means that the Delphi compiler has settings so that when generating binary files, the compiler also copies dfm files to the Unit output directory. But I did not find such settings.

The question is how to achieve that the compiler copied dfm files to the folder specified in the "Unit output directory".

Or tell me how to properly configure the Main project so that it has access to dfm files from packages.

Comment: The DFM files in the Delphi lib folders are placed there by the installer. The compiler has no option to do that.

Comment: DFM files are Windows VCL form files storing design-time form settings. DFM files are usually located in the same folder than the unit of specific form. When compiling Delphi packages that include forms the DFM files for such Forms are built into the package itself.